# Cisco ASA Command length

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface, cisco-asa

Whenever I write some command in ASA , it hides the full command and show the bit of command . What is the way to increase the length of Commands I write in ASA, so it doesn't hide the command written on the Terminal Session? I tried to google it but not able to find the solution

```
(ASA)#sho run object-group id $
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need to modify the [terminal width parameter](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/t.html#wp1483720) on the ASA to a value greater than the default of 80 columns.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in config mode

```
(config)# terminal ?

configure mode commands/options:
  width  Set terminal width, default is 80 columns

exec mode commands/options:
  monitor  Syslog monitor
  no       Turn off syslogging to this terminal
  pager    Control page length for pagination. The page length set here is not saved to configuration.
```